# SQL Data merge into one table

Tags: sql, database

Okay so my boss wants me to write a report about our patients insurances. I've never wrote in SQL before and i'm having a little trouble. The issue is, I have like 300 databases I finally found where all the information I need is but I want to put this all in one table where the IDs match with the insurances.
we will say one database is called Insurance_primary_seconday which obviously holds the primary and secondary info it has their names listed also but we don't want their names only their payID now we can find their payID listed in another database on this server which is something like insurance_crossover
I know I have to do like an inner join type thing hopefully I gave enough information to help lead me in the right direction

Comment: Thank you guys I got the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify all the tables in different databases and there relationship between tables to do the join thing. As you mentioned different databases in same server you need to append the respective database name to all the table in joins (Based on the DBMS your using). in sql server

```
Select * from DATABASE_NAME1.TABLE_NAME1 join DATABASE_NAME2.TABLE_NAME2 on Condition...so on
```

Hope it helps you !

Comment: that's what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: @JakeMcmillion glad it helped you. :)